# How to get Linux guest VMs installed in VirtualBox after upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using VirtualBox `6.1`. I it is e.g. an Ubuntu `20.04` Server VM, that were working fine. But since I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, the VMs became instable. Sometimes it cannot connect external (internet) resources, sometimes it cannot start, sometimes it cannot be shut down. Anyway, it still working... somehow. The current problem is: I cannot create new VMs. Or better: I can create one and pass the first installation steps (like language, keyboard layout, etc.), but the installation (in this case Ubuntu `20.04` Server or Ubuntu `20.04` Desktop) fails: The last step I can execute is the form with the name, username, hostname, and password. When I'm done with it and want to go to the next step, I get this error:

> Sorry, there was a problem completing the installation.

[image]

What migt have caused this troubles after the upgrade? Or is it not related to the upgrade at all? **How to get now VMs installed (again)?**

Comment: "since I upgraded from Windows to Windows 10".. So the only assumption that I can make is that you upgraded from LESS THAN 10 to 10.  Was it 7? VISTA? 98se?  It would help to clarify this for future people searching for this problem.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Oh, I see now, I just skipped the version number. Fixed. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

In place upgrades sometimes cause issues.

> I'm using VirtualBox 6.1. ...  since I upgraded from Windows to
> Windows 10 the VMs became unstable

**First:**  For this issue, uninstall Virtual Box, restart, install VB again and try your machines.

**Second**  If you continue to have issues, run a Windows 10 Repair Install to correct upgrade issues.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

Start with the option to Keep Everything.

**Third (Follow-up):**  You said, in response to my suggestion above, that you reinstalled Windows completely, which means you reinstalled Virtual Box along with all your other software, without good results.

Try installing a brand new 32-bit virtual machine to see if that works and if (possibly) Hardware Virtualization got disabled.

**Finally:**   When everything fails, back everything up and re-install Windows.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your answer. Here is my late response: Ive tried both today. First I reinstalled VirtualBox (removed and installed again). This haven't helped. And right now I've reinstalled Windows 10 (there was nor "repair") option, so I just followed the installations steps like for a new installation. Also no effect.

Comment: I added a followup note for you to try. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I reinstalled Windows 10, but not all the programs. So I did not erase the disk. To be honest, I would like to avoid this step, just as _installing a brand new 32-bit machine_ since it would be a huge effort to restore all the software and the settings etc. after that.

Comment: What I meant was to try a brand new 32-bit virtual machine (not host machine). That should not take much time. Sorry to have confused things.

Comment: OK, just tried this out. I downloaded a Windows image and tried to create a VM with it. But it failed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlH1v.png ("_Windows cannot install required files. The file may be corrupt or missing.  Make sure all files required for installation are available, and restart the installation. Error code: 0x80070570._")

Comment: I think you are going to have to completely reinstall Windows (Host system). Everything else has failed so there is nothing left but reinstall.